# SQL query not showing results

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I want to do some visualization on Tableau with AdventureWorks 2014 data but my data is not showing on Tableau. I ran the query on SQL server-it ran successfully but did not show results. I need Product Cost, Product ID and Sales reason on Tableau. Kindly help.

SQL extract

```
Select * from 
[Production].[ProductCostHistory] as pc
inner join [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] as sod
on pc.ProductID=sod.ProductID
inner join [Sales].[SalesReason] as sr
on pc.ModifiedDate=sr.ModifiedDate
```

Comment: Did you checked the db connectivity?

Comment: Well, if there were no results in sql-server when you ran that, why would you think there would be data in Tableau? BTW, without looking at your data, I'm betting `on pc.ModifiedDate=sr.ModifiedDate` is wrong.

Comment: why are you joining to sales reason on Modified Date?

Comment: I needed reasons why a product is purchased and the cost of producing it. Also , I did the join on Tableau first without success before I reexamined same on SQL server. Thanks in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong... specifically the join on SalesReason. You are going to want to look at the [SalesOrderHeaderSalesReason](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124510(v=sql.100).aspx) table, and the [SalesOrderHeader](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124879(v=sql.100).aspx) table at a minimum. Start with the [Sales Schema](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124894(v=sql.100).aspx) and go from there.

[Here's a good diagram of the Data Model](https://moidulhassan.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/adventureworks2008_schema.gif) for the Sales Schema (part of it). There are others out there easily found on google.